# Pass whole row to DB function as an argument SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I need to implement following SQL expression using **SQLAlchemy 1.4.41, Postgres 13.6**

```
SELECT book.name,
       my_func(book) AS func_result
FROM book WHERE book.name = 'The Adventures of Tom Sawyer';
```

Is there a way to implement such SQL expression?

Function is the following and I'm not supposed to change it:

```
create function my_func(table_row anyelement) returns json
```

I assume that passing `Book` to `func.my_func` is not correct as SQLAlchemy unpacks it to list of Book attributes (ex. `book.id, book.name, book.total_pages`)

```
from db.models import Book
from sqlalchemy import func, select

function = func.my_func(Book)
query = select(Book.name, function).where(Book.name == 'The Adventures of Tom Sawyer')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, you would do this by passing a row object to the function.  For example, `row_to_json` is a function that accepts a `row` and returns JSON, so given this table

```
                                    Table "public.users"
      Column       │       Type        │ Collation │ Nullable │           Default            
═══════════════════╪═══════════════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪══════════════════════════════
 id                │ integer           │           │ not null │ generated always as identity
 name              │ character varying │           │          │ 
 registration_date │ date              │           │          │
```

this query

```
select name, row_to_json(users) from users;
```

could return

```
 name  │                       row_to_json                        
═══════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 Alice │ {"id":1,"name":"Alice","registration_date":"2022-10-27"}
 Bob   │ {"id":2,"name":"Bob","registration_date":"2022-10-27"}
```

Translating this to SQLAlchemy, if you are only passing the columns from the table underlying the model (so no relationships), you can use [FromClause.table_valued](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.table_valued) as a shortcut.

```py
q = sa.select(User.name, sa.func.row_to_json(User.__table__.table_valued()))
```

If you do require values from relationships, or only a subset of the table's fields, you need to use a subquery to specify the them<sup>*</sup>:

```py
subq = sa.select(User.id, User.name).subquery()                                                                           
q = sa.select(sa.func.row_to_json(subq.table_valued()))
```

---

<sup>*</sup> This part of the answer is inspired by [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/72139/151124) by [Anatoly Ressin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44223/anatoly-ressin).